# iMac use gcc to compile c or c++ file "stdio.h: no such file or directory"

Tags: macos, gcc

I just update my iMac computer to Mac Os x 10.9, but when I open the terminal and use gcc to compile my c or c++ file, it doesn't work. When I write a simple code like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  printf("hello");
  return 0;
}
```

and `gcc -o hello hello.c` to compile it, it just says

> "stdio.h: no such file or directory"

Comment: I don't think its installed correctly because that should work.

Comment: I figure out this problem by installing Xcode 5.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the XCode Command Line Tools.

Comment: in 10.9, installing command line tools is no longer XCode beholden. You can (must) install it from the command line ==> run `xcode-select --install`

Comment: You may also be able to do that; I downloaded and installed a set of XCode Command Line Tools from the Apple Developer web site. The rules they are achanging, so there may also be other ways to do it.